# Incorporating Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm new to Java and need to employ polymorphism into the following lines:

```
horse.feed();
horse.wash();
horse.exercise();
```

How do I do this?

These are the first lines of the code in this exercise:

```
public class Main extends Object {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Horse horse = new horse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Employ polymorphism to achieve what?

Comment: I need to replace the operations in those 3 lines(the .feed, .wash, .exercise) by using polymorphism. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: They're asking you to have a class like Animal, which also can feed, wash and exercise which is extended by Horse to do these differently.

Comment: Create an interface called Animal, and declare the 3 methods in it (they can be empty).  Then create a class called Horse which implements Animal - in this you should implement each of the 3 methods. eg. public String feed() { return "Feeding horse";}

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've only been at Java about a month so far. Could someone write out how it should look so I can better understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question from your comment: "Could someone write out how it should look so I can better understand it."

Let's create an interface `Animal`

```
public interface Animal {
    public void feed();
    public void wash();
    public void exercise();
}
```

And a class `Horse`:

```
public class Horse implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void feed() {
        // Do something to feed the horse
    }

    @Override
    public void wash() {
        // Do something to wash the horse
    }

    @Override
    public void exercise() {
        // Do something to exercise the horse
    }
}
```

Now in your main method, you can create a `horse` that is an `Animal` and call the methods:

```
Animal horse = new Horse();
horse.wash();
// Etcetera
```

Now if you would make a class `Dog`, which also implements `Animal`, you could make a `List` of `Animals` and add `Horses` and `Dogs` to one `List`!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. It certainly helps me understand it better seeing it written out.

Comment: Can someone tell me why when I run this code it says "illegal start of an expression" for the line public class Horse implements Animal?

Comment: @MJW you should post the entire class up - probably best to do this in a new question